# Вопрос про dict.items()

Tags: python, dict

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цель: После того как разбил dict на пары хотел отдельно вывести одну из пар - выдает ошибку. Почему? В описании ошибки пишет, что это объект(еще не изучал эту тему). И почему в output при выводе пар в начале перед кортежом стоит dict_items???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `dict.items()` возвращает объект типа `dict_items`, для которого операция индексирования не реализована.

```
In [120]: dict1 = {i:str(i) for i in range(1,6)}

In [121]: dict1
Out[121]: {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5'}

In [122]: type(dict1)
Out[122]: dict

In [123]: di = dict1.items()

In [124]: type(di)
Out[124]: dict_items
```

попробуйте так:

```
In [129]: lst = list(dict1.items())

In [130]: type(lst)
Out[130]: list

In [131]: lst
Out[131]: [(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4'), (5, '5')]

In [132]: lst[0]
Out[132]: (1, '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: объект dict_items не поддерживает индексирование

> Один из изменений Python 3s заключается в том, что items() теперь возвращают итераторы, и список никогда не строится полностью.

```
for i in pairs:
    print(i)

(1, '1')
(2, '2')
(3, '3')
(4, '4')
(5, '5')
```